# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError' while importing a downloaded Python module into Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, file, import, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded module.py file, it saved in download folder. While importing it to jupyter it is showing an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import module as m

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Path of downloaded module.py file is `C:\Users\meena\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\ana\Lib`.

Then I open new Jupyter file and tried to import. I have no prior experience with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Couldn’t you install this Modul by pip in your python env?

Comment: You must either include the `module.py` file in the subdirectory/folder where you wish to import it (i.e. the directory of the file you are working with). Or, you must copy & paste the file in a folder called `site-packages` in the Python folder. Proabably available in `C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/<python version>/Lib`

Answer (score 0):

It could be great that you provide us more information. In the mean time, check in which environment are you working on and in which environment are you installing the module.